# Database driver change error in laravel/backpack

Tags: mysql, odbc, sqlsrv, laravel-backpack

i am using sqlsrv i want to move db to mysql, i edited .env file to

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=admin_fms
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

and run `php artisan config:cache` but i giving this error, i see it is still using sqlsrv adaptors

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[HY000]: [Microsoft][ODBC
> Driver 17 for SQL Server]Protocol error in TDS stream (SQL: select
> col.name from sys.columns as col join sys.objects as obj on
> col.object_id = obj.object_id where obj.type = 'U' and obj.object_id =
> object_id('users')) (View:
> ..\vendor\backpack\crud\src\resources\views\base\auth\login.blade.php)

My database config:
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i learned to: Backpack will use whatever the Eloquent Model uses for the DB Driver. So this isn't Backpack-specific